# Why does my routing not work when I upload my webpack production build online?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have this website made using React and of course I used React Router for the routing and it works when I run on localhost. Now when I created my production build and uploaded online, clicking the link to `en/signup` for example didn't work. It showed an error page not found. So I was kind of wondering what actually went wrong here. I don't think its any problem with the bundling. Btw, I'm using Redux, React-Redux also in my project.

TLDR: Navigating to a url like `en/signup` doesn't work in production build.

Hope you guys can help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: for SPA, server need different configuration.. which server you are using?

Comment: im using cpanel webhosting server

Comment: You will need to set up your server, whichever you are using, so that all request goes to your `index.html`

Answer (score 2):

What does your webpack config look like?

Try adding this:

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'                        // <- this right here
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}
    ]
  },
  devServer: {                      // <-- and this object too
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

What I believe is happening currently is that if you navigate directly to a url, since React (and React Router) have not yet loaded, they can't take care of the url routing. So the browser navigates to static resources at `en/signup`, and of course nothing is there.

So by adding the `publicPath` value above, you're telling it to start by sending requests to root, and then when everything is loaded, the requested url is passed through.

I'm not sure if that's exactly what's going on behind the scenes, but I think the effect is correct.

Comment: I already added thos attributes to webpack config, but still doesn't work.

Comment: I was having problem with my routes, and adding both the publicPath and the devServer config, made it work

Answer (score 0):

After getting stuck on react-router for a couple of days, I read the documentation in [React Training](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start). Then I followed the quick start steps and modified it to satisfy my requirements.

```
import {
  HashRouter as Router,
  Route,
  } from 'react-router-dom';

  <Router>
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Content} />
      <Route path="/:country" component={SnaContent} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </Router>
```

This have fixed the issue for now. Hope its helpful for others who faced similar issue.